# Como dar vários prints em python no mesmo lugar do terminal?

Tags: python, formatação

Tendo o seguinte código como base:

```
for x in range(100):
    print("{}%".format (x))
```

Como poderia ser feito para que no lugar de cada valor aparecesse em uma linha diferente e sim substituído na mesma linha.

Exemplo no lugar de ter no terminal:
1
2
3
4
5
Ter primeiro o 1 depois ele "sumir" e aparecer o 2 e assim seguir até chegar no 5?

Sei que tem como fazer isso usando *C*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquisei um pouco e consegui fazer dessa maneira:

```
import sys
import time
for x in range(101):
    print("{}%".format (x))
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

O que faz o texto ser substituído é essa chamada: `sys.stdout.write("\033[F")`, pelo que eu entendi ela limpa a linha.